# Is it possible to run MapReduce locally, without HDFS and Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Given I develop MapReduce tasks in my Windows system and before moving them to HDFS cluster I would like to run MapReduce locally. I just want to check how do work my mapper logic, inputSplits, Input/Output formats etc. Is it possible?

Comment: Mapreduce localmode is there. In that case the program will execute in a single jvm.

Answer (score 8):

Hadoop runs in 3 modes.

```
1.local mode  
2.psuedo mode  
3.distributed mode.
```

The one you are looking for is the local mode. You can debug your mapreduce code from eclipse before run it in 2 or 3 modes.
[**This**](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2012/10/debugging-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in.html) step by step guide to run application in local mode helps you a lot to debug your application.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi , i was able to debug my rmr ( mapreduce in R ) by using below option by changing backend="local"

opt = rmr.options(backend = "local",
                  backend.parameters = list(hadoop = list(
                    D = "mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=2048",
                    D = paste0("mapreduce.job.reduces=", NUM_REDUCERS))))

Answer (score 1):

In Windows to execute and test the Map Reduce code  we need to take the help of cygwin (A windows to Unix simulator).

Steps to follow:
1.First install cywin.
2.set the cygpath environmental variable

now we can give local files as input to MR program.

Answer (score 1):

we can test locally through the following command:

```
cat ./*.csv | python pythonProgram.py | python mapper.py | python reducer.py
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To run a Hadoop MapReduce job on your local machine you can use [mrjob](https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/).

You can specify how to run the job with the `-r`/`--runner` option.
The default option is `-r inline` (option can be omitted) and this means that the MapReduce job will run in a single Python process on the local machine

```
python my_job.py input.txt
```

With the option `-r local` your job will run in multiple subprocesses with

> a few Hadoop features simulated

```
python my_job.py -r local input.txt
```

With the option `-r hadoop` the job will run on an Hadoop cluster (the address of the cluster needs to be configured)

```
python my_job.py -r hadoop hdfs://my_home/input.txt
```

Please refer to this [quick-start tutorial](https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/quickstart.html#writing-your-first-job).